# Intel HAXM is not shown in IntelliJ SDK Manager

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have macbook air macOS Monterey 12.6.6 and I confirmed that VMX is on in my macbook. I installed intelliJ but in SDK manager intel HAXM is not showing. I created folder in Library/Android/sdk/extra/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and HAXM intallation file .dmg file and other files in folder. I installed HAXM by running .dmg file and it is successfully installed but not shown in IntelliJ SDK Manager

[[image: intel HAXM is not shown in SDK manager and cmdline tool window][1]]

I tried using command line tool but it was reached to 7% then failed to find package.

Comment: Intel has discontinued HAXM, I assume because of this it was removed for Android SDK.

Comment: Ok, but please let me know how I run emulators, please guide me right.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Silicon (M1 processors & later) does not support Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM Technology). The HAXM Technology was designed for Intel processors to improve the quality as well as performance of the Android Emulators.

Since Apple ditched the Intel processors and now they're only releasing the Silicon processors, you may not see the HAXM option anymore in the Android Studio in the MacOS systems.

Comment: Thank you for reply, what is the solution, my macbook have Intel Processor. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: That option is gone after an update? Or, it isn't appearing in the first place?

Comment: At first installation, the option was not available for intel HAXM. But wonderful thing I experienced that when I created Virtual Device in AVD manager it did not ask for intel HAXM missing and after finish the emulator runs and APK is running now.